# How to disable proxying beans in spring

Tags: java, spring, jvm

For performance reason I want to inject implementation directly and avoid any spring interceptors to be called.

In my case I have pretty much single implementation so CHA can kick in once any spring proxies removed.

I can't find any docs on how to do that and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about AOP?

Comment: @almasshaikh yeah, that's right. Spring interceptors don't allow jvm hotspot to kick in.

Comment: see [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/61141-disabling-proxy-objects)

Comment: Can you show us how you configured the same? and your beans? And what methodology you used aspectj or something else?

Comment: Do you use @Autowired ?

Comment: It's classing wiring via xml

Comment: If you don't use any of the AOP features for e.g. @Transactional, nothing should be proxied. This can be verified through debugging.

Comment: @AndyDufresne thanks. Can you put this into answer please so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use AOP features that require runtime proxying for e.g. transaction management - @Transactional, nothing should be proxied. Go through [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring) for more details.

This can also be verified through debugging.